# mapping io device addresses in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

```
printk(" start = %p , end = %p \n",res->start ,res->end );
fbi->reg_base = ioremap_nocache(res->start, res->end - res->start);
printk(" fbi->reg_base = %p \n",fbi->reg_base);
printk(" virt_to_phys(fbi->reg_base) = %p \n", virt_to_phys(fbi->reg_base));
printk(" virt_to_bus(fbi->reg_base) = %p \n", virt_to_bus(fbi->reg_base));
```

The output is

```
start = 72100000 , end = 72100fff 
fbi->reg_base = 70b10000
virt_to_phys(fbi->reg_base) = a0b10000
virt_to_phys(fbi->reg_base) = a0b10000
```

Why don't I get back the `0x72100000` ?

Comment: The return value from ioremap_cache is not guaranteed to be the physical address you passed as a parameter; in fact it makes little sense to be so. Why do you care about the returned pointer value, other than if it's NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine you don't get back that address because the address that `ioremap_nocache` returns isn't guaranteed to be a virtual address, as it says [here](http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux-mandocs/2.6.4-cset-20040312_2111/ioremap_nocache.html):

> ioremap_nocache performs a *platform specific sequence of operations* to make bus memory CPU accessible via the readb/readw/readl/writeb/ writew/writel functions and the other mmio helpers. **The returned address is not guaranteed to be usable directly as a virtual address**.